# API inconsistency of Spark mllib's DistributedMatrix subclasses

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

In Spark's `MLlib`, why are the computational interfaces provided for different distributed matrices inconsistent? For example, `RowMatrix` and `IndexRowMatrix` provide the `computeSVD` method, while `CoordinateMatrix` and `BlockMatrix` do not.

Why is this?

Comment: The core of most linear algebra algorithms are row operations. Those will be very expensive and inefficient if the data for a single row is spread among multiple partitions, which could easily be the case for both `CoordinateMatrix` and `BlockMatrix`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because SVD algorithm needs a row-oriented (or column-oriented) matrix format.

If `CoordinateMatrix` and `BlockMatrix` exposed a `computeSVD` method, under the hood it would need to trigger a (potentially expensive) conversion.